# Split array on delimiter but keep part of the delimiter

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to split a string on the follow delimiter `}--{`, but I would like to keep the braces.

Example:

```
"{this}--{is}--{an}--{example}"  --> ["{this}","{is}","{an}","{example}"]
```

I can't split on the `--` sequence on its own because some of the individual elements will have this sequence. Is this possible in Java?

Comment: Why not change your delimiter to a string which won't appear in your sequence like |@| or some strange combo? Or is the information passed to you in that format?

Comment: How about, first splitting and then concatenate the prefix and postfix as per requirements?

Comment: time to up your regex game ma man ;)  [try here](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: @RyanWilson That is an option, although I originally ran into this case because I had assumed the data I received wouldn't have any `--` to begin with. I think a longer gibberish delimiter will do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you would like to keep part of the delimiter, put the parts that you would like to keep into [lookahead and lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), as follows:

```
String[] parts = str.split("(?<=\\})--(?=\\{)");
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/D9qshc)